# Qt connect are not working when window is in fullscreen mode

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, signals-slots

I have got problem with some connection:

```
QAction* fs = new QAction(this);
fs->setShortcut(Qt::Key_F);
connect(fs, &QAction::triggered, this, &MainWindow::fullscreen);
menuBar()->addAction(fs);
```

And the fullscreen function is:

```
if(!fullscreenMode)
{
    mouseMoved=time(0);
    this->menuBar()->hide();
    this->showFullScreen();
    fullscreenMode=true;
}
else
{
    this->menuBar()->show();
    timeBar->show();
    controlBar->show();
    this->showNormal();
    fullscreenMode=false;
    timeBar->visibilityChanged(true);
    controlBar->visibilityChanged(true);

}
```

I can't get back to normal mode using shortcut ( F button), but I can do it using double click which is using the same function. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:

```
QShortcut* fullscreenShortcut = new QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::Key_F),this,SLOT(fullscreen()));
```

Answer (score -1):

Have "fullscreenMode" been initialized when the MainWindow is created?

Here comes 2 problems :

1. undefined fullscreenMode cause unexpected result.
2. QAction triggered pass a boolean parameter, if your function - "fullscreen" has a parameter too, the "fullscreen" will catch this parameter which pass from triggered(). Also , if the action is checkable, the boolean parameter is true if the action is checked, or false if the action is unchecked.

Hope these can help.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. Well, fullscreenMode has been initialized in MainWindow constructor, and my "fullscreen" function doesn't have a parameter.